# Filename with extension from mime string

Tags: c++, mime, file-extension, tizen

I have mime as a string and httpheader how can i get the file name with extension from the http header or simply is there any way to get extension from mime?

Eg:
              `MIME,Extension`

```
 `application/octet-stream  class`
 `application/octet-stream  dms`
` application/octet-stream  exe`
 `application/octet-stream  lha`
```

the above has same mime string but different extensions

These are the things which i get from `httpHeader` for a zip file

```
Keep-Alive : timeout=10

Connection : Keep-Alive

Age : 4418

Accept-Ranges : bytes

ETag : "ee0043-157f-4acf6ff5c1640"

Cache-Control : max-age=10800, s-maxage=10800

x-mii-cache-hit : 1

X-Pb-Mii : Powered by Mirror Image Internet

Via : 1.1 sjc005158 (MII-APC/2.3), 1.1 sjc005112 (MII-APC/2.3)

Content-Length : 5503

Last-Modified : Thu, 15 Sep 2011 08:52:33 GMT

Date : Tue, 26 Nov 2013 08:30:27 GMT

Content-Type : application/zip

Server : MII-APC/2.4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could if you really wanted to using a list like [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full) but maybe it's not the best way.

Another approach is to use `Content Disposition` header if it's available:

```
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Myfile.txt
```

And then parse the file name and extension from there

Comment: i know the first way , theres duplicate as i mentioned in the question.. I dont get these things in header

Comment: How about parsing the URL in order to get the file name and extension?

Comment: There may not have file name or extension

Comment: I think if they don't have file name or extension, they must have the Content-Disposition header.

Comment: See my update in question . thats what in there in httpheader